# how to store variable in database using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to store a variable in the database that has a certain value and when the user clicks it again then it updates the database column with the new value.

**My code**:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1'])) {

    if ( $submit[msurf] >= $msurfclicks ) {
        $sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO d_bonus VALUES('$userid','0.02',NOW())"); 
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
       echo "wrong";
    }
    header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should use laravel. I consider you try some basic laravel tutorials on laracast to get the basic concept of everything like routing.

Comment: i have took basic tutorials i actually wanna know how to add such button usig php or java script @FrankProvost my project is based on laravel

Comment: If you want the javascript part of this, why are you asking for the php part? Looking at your code I think this has basically nothing to do with laravel, it's basic php. You don't use the facades, eloquent, models etc. however, I still hope my answer givies you some hints about a better approach

Comment: I actually edited my answer and added a few more snippets to make everything work

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment I think you should start with basic laravel tutorial to get more knowledge on the basic concepts, however here's how you can solve your problem.

Assuming you have a table "d_bonus" with an user_id and an "amount"

```
// get current values
$amount = DB::table('d_bonus')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

// increase amount
$amount += 2;

// store new amount
DB::table('d_bonus')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->update(['amount' => $amount]);

// redirect
return redirect('/my-route');
```

Dont forget to add `use Auth;` and `use DB;`

However, I suggest creating relations between the user and the course to learn this up. You would then not need to use `DB` directly.

**Update**:

To make a button which calls this you will at least need a route calling this code

e.g.

```
Route::get('clicked-my-button', function() {
   // put code here, dont forget to add facaeds in header
   // better use a controller instead of a function within your routes!
});
```

Your form will be like

```
 <form action="/clicked-my-button" method="GET">
     {{csfr_field()}} <!-- hopefully you are using blade -->
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use model for your table , you can use firstOrCreate or firstOrNew method for your work.

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);

// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrNew(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

for mor information :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent